# Switching From a windows machine, How will my data drive transfer to a linux system?

Tags: ssd, windows-10, mongodb

I'm looking to make the switch to linux on my desktop. Right now I have a boot drive ssd running windows and a data drive. I'm commited to solely running Ubuntu Mate 16, but I'm worried about my data drive. Particularly, I have a mongodb stored there that I don't want to lose. If I leave my data drive untouched, and wipe my SSD and put linux on that, will I still be able to access my database on my data drive? Or would it not work?

Comment: See for yourself: Create a LiveUSB ("Try Ubuntu" without installing), install MongoDB to the test environment, and check your database yourself. Then you will *know* if it will work...without risking your current system. Backup all data before mucking with OS testing and changes.

Comment: What filesystem is your data drive running? Are you also changing MongoDB server versions? The MongoDB data files are cross-platform, but possible speedbumps to watch out for are filesystem performance differences (NTFS on Linux vs Windows) and compatible MongoDB server versions in your Windows & Linux environments. If you are upgrading to a newer version of MongoDB as part of your Ubuntu install you should review the relevant [MongoDB release notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/) and upgrade documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unplug the data drive when installing Ubuntu. (for peace of mind)
2. Ubuntu is supported by the MongoDB Community. or you can [Dual-Boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/187789/dual-booting-explained-how-you-can-have-multiple-operating-systems-on-your-computer/) Windows with  Ubuntu

   [how to install MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)